# Access object in interprocess shared memory without violating strict aliasing rules

Tags: c++, ipc, c++17, shared-memory, interprocess

I have multiple programs written in C++17, running on Linux.

One program creates a file under /dev/shm/ and maps it to it's memory space.  It then proceeds to use placement-new to initialize a POD object in the shared memory.

The other processes will open and map these files into their memory spaces to access the object.  Currently, I'm using a C-style cast, which works, but I believe it's technically undefined behavior per the C++ aliasing rules, so this could break in a future version of GCC.

The compiler has no idea that an object exists at that memory location.  Normally, I would communicate this to the compiler by invoking placement-new, but in this case that would initialize-over the existing object (which I believe would also be undefined behavior).

How am I supposed to access this object without violating strict aliasing rules?
Is this a use case for [std::launder](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)?

Comment: Placement new doesn't initialize POD. However, You should take special measures to prevent race conditions like a mutex lock. That depends a great deal on your design.

Answer (score 2):

The mmap functions returns a void pointer and the strict type aliasing rules do not apply to void pointers since they are not pointing to an actual type but need to be casted to something before access. So it is in C++ totally legal to use C-like casts or better static_casts on void pointers.

But it can become an optimisation problem if you access data in shared memory. Your compiler is allowed to assume that the RAM is not changed by something if he can see all calls. So you have to put for example mutexes around it to ensure that your compiler can't see every possible access and have to reload the data.

Comment: But an object only comes into existence via creating it on the stack as a local variable or via a new-expression.  That's why it's invalid in C++ to just malloc some memory and then cast it to whatever object type you want.  Why would that be legal in the case of mmap'd memory?

Comment: @SumDood You shall not create the object on the stack but use pointers. So in all but one process you use: myType *var = static_cast<myType*>(shared_mem+offset); and in one process: myType *var=new (shared_mem+offset)(myType);